# How to use [submission:values] in Email template in Webforms

Tags: webforms, emails

I have the Webform 7.x-4.0-alpha6 version module enabled.

I have a Webform node with 20 form components. I added one email in Email Setting and I created the email template where I used the token: **[submission:values]**.

Then I test the webform submitting a message. The problem is that **[submission:values]** print out the components values in a very plain way, no break line, no semicolon to make a difference between the **title** and the **value** for each component. Something like:

```
Name Jhon
Addresss Myaddress 12 
CP 19932
....
```

Having 20 component make the email completely **unreadable**

**My question is:** Is there a way (a token) to print them in a better way, at least adding a semicolon between the title and value, and making the title **bold** ? or putting the output in a table?

```
    Name: Jhon
    Addresss: Myaddress 12 
    CP: 19932
```

I know that I can print out the components in a separated way using the tokens:
[webform:{component}-title] for the title
and 
[webform:{component}-value] for the value

And then I can style them. But this is time wasting since I need all components to be shown in the email template

Update: I found this module but doesn't help me: http://drupal.org/project/webform_tokens

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't such problem, but I know, how to get special values from webform.

> Webform tokens from submitted data. Includes the value and field label. Replace the "`?`" with the "*Field Key*". Append "`:nolabel`" for just the value.

So, you can use `[submission:values:?:nolabel]`, where `?` is field key of your component.

```
 Name: [submission:values:name:nolabel]
 Address: [submission:values:address:nolabel]
```

For me result is the same as for `[submission:values]`:

> Name: Kate
>   Address: Moscow, Russia :)

Webform version: 7.x-4.0-alpha6 (7404).

Webform Tokens module is not needed.

### Update

If you are using HTML mail, labels are outputted via `theme_form_element_label` and look like `<label>Title</label>\n`.

You can override `webform-submission.tpl.php`. Copy this file to the theme for rendering the emails from `admin/config/system/mailsystem`.
To add `:` I suggest just to modify render array:

```
if ($format == 'html') {
  foreach ($renderable as $i => $item) {
    if (is_array($item) && !empty($item['#title'])) {
      $renderable[$i]['#title'] .= ':';
    }
  }
}

print drupal_render_children($renderable);
```

But you can output substitutions fully yourself.

Comment: what you said is a valid option but I have to repeat this line set 20 times. I'm looking for a one line to output all the 20 components at once.

Comment: @chefnelone I updated my answer.

Comment: I think you are close but... I just use the dpm function for the $renderable array and there is no $item['#title'] inside. Maybe you are on the webform version 3. I'm using version 4 beta6. Look my capture: http://content.screencast.com/users/chefnelone/folders/Snagit/media/c08b754f-2be5-4129-bca8-2ccc94a13e7e/2012-11-09_15-44-12.png

Comment: Your code is right. It is just I'm nesting the webform components and I will need to change this line `if (is_array($item) && !empty($item['#title'])) {` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Send e-mail as HTML** option of webform.

This is available if you install the [Mime Mail](https://drupal.org/project/mimemail) and [Mail System](https://drupal.org/project/mailsystem) modules, then go to `admin/config/content/webform` and set the **Format** to *HTML*.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that if you're using a *Grid* component, you need to call that token with both the Field Key and then the question key. Grids are often used if you're doing a survey, for example and are asking people to rate something on a scale of 1-3, using radio buttons for each row, such as:

Sample Question:

Rank the following with 1=high, 3=lowest

```
+---------------+-----+-----+-----+
|   Breweries   |  1  |  2  |  3  |
+---------------+-----+-----+-----+
| Lighthouse    | [o] | [o] | [o] |
| Phillips      | [o] | [o] | [o] |
| Whistler      | [o] | [o] | [o] |
+---------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

To print out the value of just question 2's answer, you'd use:
Beer Question 2 value was: [submission:values:my_beer_field:phillips]