# How to customize the email subject for a webform?

Tags: 7, webforms, tokens

I am using Webform 7.x-4.0 on Drupal 7.24 and I am trying to customise the email subject for my webform.
I have followed the instructions as per the instructions in this post [How to use [submission:values] in Email template in Webforms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50086/how-to-use-submissionvalues-in-email-template-in-webforms/50098#50098) but when I save the settings, the email subject is blank.

I entered [submission:values:event_type] for the custom field and my field key is as follows:

[image: field key]

After saving the configuration, the field turns up blank.

[image: email]

The email sent out just shows -no subject given as the subject of the email.

Answer (score 2):

So, I think you're using the UI wrong. Each of those email templates you have should be to a different user and it doesn't look like you've added an email to anyone.

Below where you have your Value of "Event Type" line there's the option to send an email to a specific email address (I.E the admin) or to add an email to the value of the Email token, you need to add and save an email to a specific person there and add a subject using your token substitution there. Or at least that's what it looks like from what you posted.[image]

[image: Two emails]