# Customise Webform Email Submission Data

Tags: webforms, emails, theming

In the webform-mail.tpl.php template, it outputs the main form data using:

```
[submission:values]
```

I am using the html format (using mime-mail) and this outputs to the email html in the form:

```
<div><label>Name</label>Name value</div>
```

Is there a way I can customise the output so that it doesn't use the label field and uses a `<p>` tag instead?

The problem with the `<label>` tag is that I cannot style it in Microsoft Outlook as it ignores all styling for this tag, and the email is quite difficult to read/understand.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer from an identical question at [How to use [submission:values] in Email template in Webforms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50086/how-to-use-submissionvalues-in-email-template-in-webforms).

Using the webform-submissions.tpl.php template I changed the output structure from:

```
<div><label>Name</label>Name value</div>
```

to:

```
<div><p class="label">Name</p><p class="value">Name Value</p></div>
```

Using the code below:

```
<?php 
if ($format == 'html') {
    $output = drupal_render_children($renderable);
    $output = preg_replace('/<label.*?>/', '<p class="label">', $output);
    $output = str_replace(' </label>', ':</p><p class="value">', $output);
    $output = str_replace('</div>', '</p></div>', $output);
    print $output;
}
?>
```

Now the styling in my Outlook emails look much better :)