# Customise Webform Email Submission Data 2

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

I had read some info from this content: [How to use [submission:values] in Email template in Webforms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50086/how-to-use-submissionvalues-in-email-template-in-webforms)

Submitted on [submission:date:long] 
Submitted by user: [submission:user] 
Submitted values are: 
[submission:values]

The results of this submission may be viewed at:
[submission:url]

Name: [submission:values:name:nolabel]
Address: [submission:values:address:nolabel]

I add last two code in the email setting, but it only print name: and address:

I also try this %email_values %email[name], but it print out as string.

What wrong with my code?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Are those fields inside a fieldset? This has tripped me up a few times. Fields in a fieldset need to be [submission:values:fieldset-name:name:nolabel]

Comment: Haha no problem. Ive added it as an answer so you can mark it.

Comment: @Collins, are you administrator? I wonder can I ask question like any recommend responsive theme??

Comment: have a look at http://www.devsaran.com/ he comes up with some good responsive starter themes that are all free.

Comment: Many Thanks for you info. I had manages to solve submission code. Now I have another problem. I try to style bullet with image. <ul style="list-style-image: url('http://www.example.com/bullet.png');"> I tested in normal html is working. Do I need module to make this work?

Comment: Are you trying to send the bullet point inside the email? You will need HTML mail for this to work, try the mine mail module. Post it as a new question if you need more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those fields inside a fieldset? This has tripped me up a few times.

Fields in a fieldset need to be [submission:values:fieldset-name:name:nolabel]